# .NET EF order user by multiple dates

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on a .NET project where I am utilizing Entity Framework. I require assistance with sorting users by date. Specifically, I need to sort users based on multiple dates. In the user entity, there are createDate and updateDate fields. Additionally, each user contains a list of items, each of which also possesses createDate and updateDate attributes.

My objective is to sort users by the latest user date or user items last update or create date among the following: user.createDate, user.updateDate, item.createDate, and item.updateDate.

But if I update user item and the item will have updated date I also need to prefer this user with updated item. This mean if the user item date is newer then other user create or update date, the user with updated item will be preferred.

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; };
        public string LastName { get; set; };
    public string Email { get; set; };
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; };
    public Datetime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Datetime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public Datetime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Datetime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I tried for example this, where i try to use ordering by multiple columns, but in this situation the user with updated item is not preferred.

```cs
users = users
    .OrderByDescending(u => u.UpdatedAt ?? u.CreatedAt)
    .ThenByDescending(u => u.Items.Any() ? u.Items.Max(i => i.UpdatedAt ?? i.CreatedAt) : DateTime.MinValue)
```

Could you please advise on how I can achieve this sorting only with working with IQueryable? Is this feasible?

I need to implement function that take reference to iqueryable end sort the users

```
private static void UserSortByActivity(ref IQueryable<User> users)
{
            
}
```

Example of data:

```cs
List<User> users = new List<User>
{
    new User
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe",
        createdDate = "2021-01-01",
        UpdatedDate = null,
        Items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Item1",
                CreatedDate = "2021-01-01",
                UpdatedDate = "2021-01-02",
            },
            new Item
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Item2",
                CreatedDate = "2021-01-01",
                UpdatedDate = "2021-01-03",
            },
        }
    },
    new User
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = "Jane",
        LastName = "Doe",
        createdDate = "2021-02-01",
        UpdatedDate = "2021-02-02",
        Items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Item3",
                CreatedDate = "2021-02-01",
                UpdatedDate = "2021-02-02",
            },
            new Item
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Item4",
                CreatedDate = "2021-02-01",
                UpdatedDate = "2021-06-03",
            },
        }
    },
    new User
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = "Alice",
        LastName = "Smith",
        createdDate = "2021-03-01",
        UpdatedDate = "2021-03-02",
        Items = new List<Item>();
    },
};
```

Possible sorted output

First: Jane Doe (last updated item on 2021-06-03)

Second: Alice Smith (last user updated on 2021-03-02)

Third: John Doe (last updated item on 2021-01-03)

Comment: Have you tried `OrderBy...ThenBy...ThenBy...`? i.e `users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName).ThenBy(u => u.FirstName).ThenByDescending(u => u.CreateDate);`

Comment: Yes, but this do not work, if I for example update the user item it will not prefer newer date from item but still the user date.

```csharp
users = users
.OrderByDescending(u => u.UpdatedAt ?? u.CreatedAt)
.ThenByDescending(u => u.Items.Any() ? u.Items.Max(i => i.UpdatedAt ?? i.CreatedAt) : DateTime.MinValue)
```

Comment: "but this do not work" Do you get an error message, or are the results simply not ordered the way you expect?

Comment: The result is just not ordered the way i expect. Because it still prefer order by user.create or user.update but I i update the user item it will not move the user on top

Comment: @ERROR_404 that doesn't mean `it doesn't work`. It means you wanted a specific order that' isn't mentioned in the question. Edit the question and ask what you really want, with examples and the code you tried. Multi-column sorting is shown in all tutorials. What you ask isn't multi-column sorting, it's something else. Make that logic clear in the question itself

Comment: What you ask is how to order by the maximum of the parent and children dates, not by multiple fields. In SQL you'd need a subquery or CTE to calculate that. In LINQ that means a `Select` that produces the desired values before ordering, eg `.Select(u=>new {User=u,ItemsFirstUpdate=u.Items.Min(i=>Updated), ItemsLastUpdate=u.Items.Max(i=>Updated),....})`

Comment: Please add some sample data and intended output, that probably clarifies a lot.

Comment: Note that if you choose to always set the updatedDate the same as the createdDate during creation, you can effectively ignore the createdDate during all of this sorting logic, halving the amount of work you need to do. You can do this and e.g. blank it out at the *presentation* level if they're still equal.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated the issue you are describing in console app and this is a solution I came up with and works as expected

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Simulate a list of users with items as you might retrieve from a database
        List<User> users = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                Items = new List<Item>
                {
                    new Item
                    {
                        Name = "Item1",
                        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                        UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 2),
                    },
                    new Item
                    {
                        Name = "Item2",
                        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                        UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 1, 3),
                    },
                }
            },
            new User
            {
                FirstName = "Jane",
                LastName = "Doe",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 1),
                UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 2),
                Items = new List<Item>
                {
                    new Item
                    {
                        Name = "Item3",
                        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 1),
                        UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 2),
                    },
                    new Item
                    {
                        Name = "Item4",
                        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 1),
                        UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 6, 3),
                    },
                }
            },
            new User
            {
                FirstName = "Alice",
                LastName = "Smith",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 3, 1),
                UpdatedDate = new DateTime(2021, 3, 2),
                Items = new List<Item>() // No items for Alice
            },
        };


        var sortedUsersWithReason = users
            .Select(u => new
            {
                User = u,
                MostRecentDate = new[]
                {
                    u.CreatedDate,
                    u.UpdatedDate ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                    u.Items.Any() ? u.Items.Max(i => i.CreatedDate) : DateTime.MinValue,
                    u.Items.Any() ? u.Items.Max(i => i.UpdatedDate ?? DateTime.MinValue) : DateTime.MinValue
                }.Max(),
                SortReason = u.UpdatedDate.HasValue && (!u.Items.Any() || u.UpdatedDate.Value >= u.Items.Max(i => i.UpdatedDate ?? i.CreatedDate)) ?
                    $"last user updated on {u.UpdatedDate.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}" :
                    $"last updated item on {u.Items.Max(i => i.UpdatedDate ?? i.CreatedDate):yyyy-MM-dd}"
            })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.MostRecentDate)
            .ToList();


        // Display the sorted users
        foreach (var entry in sortedUsersWithReason)
        {
            string reasonPhrase;
            
            if (entry.User.UpdatedDate.HasValue && entry.User.UpdatedDate.Value == entry.MostRecentDate)
            {
                reasonPhrase = $"last user updated on {entry.User.UpdatedDate.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}";
            }
            else if (entry.User.CreatedDate == entry.MostRecentDate)
            {
                
                reasonPhrase = $"last user created on {entry.User.CreatedDate:yyyy-MM-dd}";
            }
            else
            {
                // Find the most recent item update or creation date
                var mostRecentItemUpdate = entry.User.Items
                    .Select(i => i.UpdatedDate ?? i.CreatedDate)
                    .OrderByDescending(d => d)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                reasonPhrase = $"last updated item on {mostRecentItemUpdate:yyyy-MM-dd}";
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{entry.User.FirstName} {entry.User.LastName} ({reasonPhrase})");
        }

    }

    public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is for EF Core. Seed database with data and try your query. It will be not translatable.